# SSH command Not working in MacOSX

Tags: macos, ssh

**SSH commands** always shows error 
after typing `$ssh` in terminal Killed: 9 error is coming 
Mac OS EI Captain

Comment: Satyabans-Mini:~ Satyaban$ ssh

Comment: ssh is inbuilt by Mac OS I cannot.is there is any way to reinstall

Comment: Perhaps type `ssh`instead of `$ssh`

Comment: I have not typed $ssh .$ is the by default symbol of mac terminal.
Issue have been resolved after updating my mac OS from EI Captain to Sierra